# Uso correcto de JPA InheritanceType

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, spring, jpa, herencia

Realice un proyecto hace un tiempo en Spingboot con JPA, el uso de Herencias y como Data Base PostgreSQL, en el cree un Usuario, un Profesor y un Estudiante, los dos últimos heredaban del Usuario, la herencia era InheritanceType.JOIN y al momento de realizar una Query hacia el select en usuario pero devolvía la lista de Estudiante y solo me devolvía los estudiantes, ahora repetí el mismo proceso solo cambiando la Data Base a Mysql, pero al realizar la Query de filtrar estudiantes me retorna la lista con todos los usuarios (es decir con profesores).

**Clase Usuario**
Esta es la clase de la cual heredan el profesor y estudiante

```
import com.natalia.gestionnotas.security.entity.Rol;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Usuario implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "idusuario")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int idusuario;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String nombre;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String apellido;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String correo;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String contrasenia;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "usuario_rol", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "idusuario", nullable = false),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "idrol", nullable = false))
    private Set<Rol> roles = new HashSet<>();

    /**
     *  Constructor
     */

    public Usuario() {
    }

    public Usuario(String nombre, String apellido, String correo, String contrasenia) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellido = apellido;
        this.correo = correo;
        this.contrasenia = contrasenia;
    }

    /** Getter y Setter **/
```

**Esta es la clase Estudiante**
Esta es la clase estudiante solo tiene una lista de notas y hereda los atributos de usuario

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "idusuario")
public class Estudiante extends Usuario {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "estudiante")
    private List<Nota> notas = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * Getter y Setter
     **/

    public List<Nota> getNotas() {
        return notas;
    }

    public void setNotas(List<Nota> notas) {
        this.notas = notas;
    }
}
```

Con esta Query realice la búsqueda de estudiantes en el proyecto anterior, buscaba por nombre y aunque hubiese un profesor con el mismo nombre solo traía estudiantes, pero en este caso no.

```
import com.natalia.gestionnotas.entity.Estudiante;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Repository
public interface EstudianteRepository extends JpaRepository<Estudiante, Integer> {

    @Query(value = "select * from usuario where lower(nombre) like lower(concat('%',:nombre,'%')) and lower(apellido) like lower(concat('%',:apellido,'%'))", nativeQuery = true)
    Page<Estudiante> filtrarP(String nombre, String apellido, Pageable pageable);

    Optional<Estudiante> findByCorreo(String estudiante);
}
```